# Using schtasks to create a task with multiple schedules

Tags: scheduled-tasks, administration, system-administration

Is there some way to use schtasks to create a task with multiple schedules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.  You can create a batch file and have multiple schedules point to it though.

I haven't played with Server 2008.

I've been working on a database backed scheduler at work.  Hmmm... Now that you mention it, I'd better see what new scheduling features are coming in W7.